# Clickcontext e copiar

Tags: vba, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extensão

Bom dia.

Meu codigo esta assim

```
Sub pegadadoschrome()

Dim obj As New webdriver
Dim keys As selenium.keys
Set keys = New selenium.keys
obj.Start "chrome", ""
obj.get "https://gvt.etadirect.com/"
Dim txt As String
Dim txt1 As String


obj.FindElementById("username").SendKeys ("USER1")
obj.FindElementById("password").SendKeys ("$123T*")
obj.FindElementByName("user_submitted_login_form").Click ("")
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
obj.FindElementById("password").SendKeys ("$123T*")
obj.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[4]/div[1]/form/div[5]/label/span[1]").Click ("")
obj.FindElementByName("user_submitted_login_form").Click ("")

'/COLOCA A CELULA NUMA VARIAVEL
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Planilha1").Activate
Range("A1").Select
txt = Range("A1").Copy


obj.Window.Maximize
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))


'.CLICA na aba pesquisa
obj.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]").Click ("")
obj.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[15]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div[2]/input").SendKeys (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Planilha1").Range("A1").Value)
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
obj.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[15]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tr[1]/td[2]").Click ("")
obj.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[6]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]").ClickDouble
obj.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=""elId1340""]/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]").ClickContext
```

Minha duvida dai é o seguinte.
Logo apos abrir o menu de contexto do mouse, como eu faço para "emular um click" no submenu 'copiar'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voltei pessoal.

Para passar a solução para caso alguem precise um dia.

Eu consegui resolver o problema com outro codigo ate que bem simples.

```
obj.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[15]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/table/tr[1]/td[2]").Click ("")obj.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[6]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]").Click ("")obj.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[6]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]").ClickDouble'.obj.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=""elId1340""]/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]").ClickContext SendKeys "^caret" + "c", True
```

foi so parar de executar o , "clickcontext" e troca-lo por "SendKeys "^caret" + "c", True depois do "clickdouble" que funcionou certo